# Aggregate column with list of string with intersection of the elements with Polars

Tags: python, dataframe, list, aggregation, python-polars

I'm trying to aggregate some rows in my dataframe with a `list[str]` column. For each index I need the intersection of all the lists in the group. Not sure if I'm just overthinking it but I can't provide a solution right now. Any help please?

```
import polars as pl    
input_df = pl.DataFrame(
   {"idx": [1,1,2,2,3,3], 
    "values": [["A", "B"], ["B", "C"], ["A", "B"], ["B", "C"], ["A", "B"], ["B", "C"]]
   }
)

output_df = input_df.agg(...)

>>> input_df
shape: (6, 2)
┌─────┬────────────┐
│ idx ┆ values     │
│ --- ┆ ---        │
│ i64 ┆ list[str]  │
╞═════╪════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ ["A", "B"] │
│ 1   ┆ ["B", "C"] │
│ 2   ┆ ["A", "B"] │
│ 2   ┆ ["B", "C"] │
│ 3   ┆ ["A", "B"] │
│ 3   ┆ ["B", "C"] │
└─────┴────────────┘
>>> output_df # Expected output
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ idx ┆ values    │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ list[str] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ ["B"]     │
│ 2   ┆ ["B"]     │
│ 3   ┆ ["B"]     │
└─────┴───────────┘
```

I've tried some stuff without success

```
>>> input_df.group_by("idx").agg(
  pl.reduce(function=lambda acc, x: acc.list.set_intersection(x), 
     exprs=pl.col("values"))
)
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ idx ┆ values                   │
│ --- ┆ ---                      │
│ i64 ┆ list[list[str]]          │
╞═════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [["A", "B"], ["B", "C"]] │
│ 2   ┆ [["A", "B"], ["B", "C"]] │
│ 3   ┆ [["A", "B"], ["B", "C"]] │
└─────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

Another one

```
>>> input_df.group_by("idx").agg(
   pl.reduce(function=lambda acc, x: acc.list.set_intersection(x), 
   exprs=pl.col("values").explode())
)
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬───────────────────┐
│ idx ┆ values            │
│ --- ┆ ---               │
│ i64 ┆ list[str]         │
╞═════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 3   ┆ ["A", "B", … "C"] │
│ 2   ┆ ["A", "B", … "C"] │
│ 1   ┆ ["A", "B", … "C"] │
└─────┴───────────────────┘
```

Comment: I thought I figured out how to do your `pl.reduce` attempt with `pl.fold` but I've [edited it out.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77545167/revisions) It's a) super slow and b) gives odd results for larger examples (I'm not sure if there is a bug involved, or user-error.) It does seem like it would be useful if intersection/union could accept multiple *"other"* args. Or perhaps even a top-level function so you could do `.agg(pl.set_intersection("values"))`.

Comment: I made this [feature request](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12724) as it seems what you're trying to do *should* work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is as simple as it may seem.

You could get rid of the lists and use "regular" Polars functionality.

One way to check if a value is contained in each row of the `idx` group is to count the number of unique (distinct) row numbers per `idx, values` group.

```py
(df.with_columns(group_len = pl.count().over("idx"))
   .with_row_count()
   .explode("values")
   .with_columns(num_rows =
       pl.n_unique("row_nr").over("idx", "values")
   )
)
```

```py
shape: (12, 5)
┌────────┬─────┬────────┬───────────┬──────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ idx ┆ values ┆ group_len ┆ num_rows │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ ---      │
│ u32    ┆ i64 ┆ str    ┆ u32       ┆ u32      │
╞════════╪═════╪════════╪═══════════╪══════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 1   ┆ A      ┆ 2         ┆ 1        │
│ 0      ┆ 1   ┆ B      ┆ 2         ┆ 2        │ # row_nr = [0, 1]
│ 1      ┆ 1   ┆ B      ┆ 2         ┆ 2        │
│ 1      ┆ 1   ┆ C      ┆ 2         ┆ 1        │
│ 2      ┆ 2   ┆ A      ┆ 2         ┆ 1        │
│ 2      ┆ 2   ┆ B      ┆ 2         ┆ 2        │ # row_nr = [2, 3]
│ 3      ┆ 2   ┆ B      ┆ 2         ┆ 2        │
│ 3      ┆ 2   ┆ C      ┆ 2         ┆ 1        │
│ 4      ┆ 3   ┆ A      ┆ 2         ┆ 1        │
│ 4      ┆ 3   ┆ B      ┆ 2         ┆ 2        │ # row_nr = [4, 5]
│ 5      ┆ 3   ┆ B      ┆ 2         ┆ 2        │
│ 5      ┆ 3   ┆ C      ┆ 2         ┆ 1        │
└────────┴─────┴────────┴───────────┴──────────┘
```

You can filter those, and build the list of results with `.group_by`

```py
(df.with_columns(group_len = pl.count().over("idx"))
   .with_row_count()
   .explode("values")
   .filter(
       pl.n_unique("row_nr").over("idx", "values")
        == pl.col("group_len")
   )
   .group_by("idx", maintain_order=True)
   .agg(pl.col("values").unique())
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ idx ┆ values    │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ list[str] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ ["B"]     │
│ 2   ┆ ["B"]     │
│ 3   ┆ ["B"]     │
└─────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful. I'll go this way to try to solve my bigger problem, although as you said in the other comment I think a top-level function to intersect lists would be useful!

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the fold/reduce approach is that the expressions parameter needs a list/iterator of actual expressions or at least an expression that knows it refers to multiple columns like `pl.all()`. It's not going to work as an aggregation.

You can work around that by segmenting your df by the length of each `idx` and then using a comprehension to deliver the expressions.

```
pl.concat([
    df.lazy().group_by('idx').agg(pl.col('values')).with_columns(
        values=pl.reduce(
            function = lambda acc, other: acc.list.set_intersection(other),
            exprs=[pl.col('values').list.get(n) for n in range(n_count)]
        )
    )
    for n_count, df in (      
        df
        .with_columns(n=pl.count().over('idx'))
        .partition_by('n',include_key=False, as_dict=True)
        .items()
    )
]).collect()
```

This works a lot like a pivot where we make a wide df and then refer to each column as an expression but instead of an outright pivot it creates a list of lists then just uses `get` on each of those elements as if they were columns.

##### Alternate syntax

As a response to @jqurious's comment. You can use `group_by` instead of `partition_by` but then you have to use `map_groups` with a custom function.

That might look like this:

```
def innerfunc(df):
    n_count=df.lazy().select(pl.col('n').first()).collect().item()
    # I use .lazy and .collect so it works with either eager or lazy
    return (
        df.group_by('idx').agg(pl.col('values')).with_columns(
        values=pl.reduce(
            function = lambda acc, other: acc.list.set_intersection(other),
            exprs=[pl.col('values').list.get(n) for n in range(n_count)]
        )
    )
    )

df.with_columns(n=pl.count().over('idx')).group_by('n').map_groups(innerfunc)
# We have to create n before the group_by as map_groups 
# isn't allowed when group_by is an expression.
```

Note that the first line requires a collect of the `n` because we need the list comprehension in `reduce`s expr parameter to know `n_count` in python terms. That was one of the nice benefits of using `partition_by` is that we got that through using a `as_dict`.

I presume the benefit of `group_by` is that you can then start with a Lazyframe which then requires that the schema of `map_groups` be given to it like this:

```
(
df.lazy()
.with_columns(n=pl.count().over('idx'))
.group_by('n')
.map_groups(innerfunc, schema={'idx':pl.Int64, 'values':pl.List(pl.Utf8)})
.collect()
)
```

##### Second Alternate syntax

If we convert the values list to a struct then we don't need to know how many there are, it's good enough that we know there's a unified number of them. In that way you could do it like this...

```
(
    df.lazy()
    .with_columns(n=pl.count().over('idx'))
    .group_by('n')
    .map_groups(lambda df: (
        df
        .group_by('idx')
        .agg(pl.col('values'))
        .with_columns(pl.col('values').list.to_struct())
        .unnest('values')
        .select(
            'idx',
            values=pl.reduce(
                function = lambda acc, other: acc.list.set_intersection(other),
                exprs=[pl.col('^field_.+$')]
                )
            )
        ), schema={'idx':pl.Int64, 'values':pl.List(pl.Utf8)})
    .sort('idx')
    .collect()
)
```

I'm not sure how this would parallelize so if someone wants to do a benchmark between the two with bigger starting data, it would certainly be interesting.

Comment: Can we replace `.partition_by` with `.group_by`? e.g. `for n_count, df in df.group_by(pl.count().over('idx'))`

Comment: If I just use `for n_count, df in df.group_by(pl.count().over('idx'))` your original concat approach still works. (Apologies if it was unclear, I wasn't trying to suggest `.map_groups`)

Comment: but `df.group_by(pl.count().over('idx'))` doesn't unpack into `n_count, df`...unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I thought it did: `print(list(df.group_by(pl.count().over('idx'))))`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
from functools import reduce
def get_intersection(d):
  return reduce(
    lambda x, y: list(set(x).intersection(y)), d
  )
(input_df
   .group_by('idx', maintain_order=True)
   .agg(pl.col('values').map_elements(get_intersection)))
```